# Create for loop for naming output file Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, for-loop

So i'm importing a list of names
e.g.

Textfile would include:

```
Eleen
Josh
Robert
Nastaran
Miles

my_list = ['Eleen','Josh','Robert','Nastaran','Miles']
```

Then i'm assigning each name to a list and I want to write a new excel file for each name in that list.

```
#1.   Is there anyway I can create a for loop where on the line:
temp = os.path.join(dir,'...'.xls')
_________________________  
def high_throughput(names):
    import os
    import re


# Reading file

in_file=open(names,'r')
dir,file=os.path.split(names)
temp = os.path.join(dir,'***this is where i want to put a for loop 
for each name in the input list of names***.xls')
out_file=open(temp,'w')

data = []

for line in in_file:
    data.append(line)

in_file.close()
```

Comment: What's your question then? Also, please make your code samples less broken.

Comment: Why are you assigning each name to a global? And, however and whyever you're doing that, you've still got `my_list`, so why not just use `for name in my_list:`?

Comment: i changed it a little bit.  the code i displayed for a sample has my region where I create the list of names and it extracts the data by line in the file.  i guess the list called "data" would be equivalent to "my_list"

Comment: my apologies for wording it weird if i did. it's hard for me to explain what i'm trying to do sometimes

Comment: Are you putting anything in the Excel workbooks, or just empty files?

Comment: Hi @draconisthe0ry This comment isn't for this question. It's because your question about ORF_sequences has been deleted. However, I have the complete and working code to answer to it. If you post it again, I'll be able to post it right after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you're trying to do (and by "not sure", I mean "completely baffled"), but I think I can explain some of what you're doing wrong, and how to do it right:

```
in_file=open(names,'r')
dir,file=os.path.split(names)
temp = os.path.join(dir,'***this is where i want to put a for loop 
for each name in the input list of names***.xls')
```

At this point, you don't *have* the input list of names. That's what you're reading from `in_file`, and you haven't read it yet. Later on, you read those named into `data`, after which you can use them. So:

```
in_file=open(names,'r')
dir,file=os.path.split(names)

data = []

for line in in_file:
    data.append(line)

in_file.close()

for name in data:
    temp = os.path.join(dir, '{}.xls'.format(name))
    out_file=open(temp,'w')
```

Note that I put the for loop outside the function call, because you have to do that. And that's a good thing, because you presumably want to open each path (and do stuff to each file) inside that loop, not open a single path made out of a loop of files.

But if you don't insist on using a for loop, there is something that may be closer to what you were looking for: a list comprehension. You have a list of names. You can use that to build a list of paths. And then you can use that to build a list of open files. Like this:

```
paths = [os.path.join(dir, '{}.xls'.format(name)) for name in data]
out_files = [open(path, 'w') for path in paths]
```

Then, later, after you've built up the string you want to write to all the files, you can do this:

```
for out_file in out_files:
   out_file.write(stuff)
```

However, this is kind of an odd design. Mainly because you have to close each file. They *may* get closed automatically by the garbage collection, and even if they don't, they *may* get flushed… but unless you get lucky, all that data you wrote is just sitting around in buffers in memory and never gets written to disk. Normally you don't want to write programs that depend on getting lucky. So, you want to close your files. With this design, you'd have to do something like:

```
for out_file in out_files:
   out_file.close()
```

It's probably a lot simpler to go back to the one big loop I suggested in the first place, so you can do this:

```
for name in data:
    temp = os.path.join(dir, '{}.xls'.format(name))
    out_file=open(temp,'w')
    out_file.write(stuff)
    out_file.close()
```

Or, even better:

```
for name in data:
    temp = os.path.join(dir, '{}.xls'.format(name))
    with open(temp,'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(stuff)
```

A few more comments, while we're here…

First, you really shouldn't be trying to generate .xls files manually out of strings. You can use a library like `openpyxl`. Or you can create .csv files instead—they're easy to create with the `csv` library that comes built in with Python, and Excel can handle them just as easily as .xls files. Or you can use `win32com` or `pywinauto` to take control of Excel and make it create your files. Really, anything is better than trying to generate them by hand.

Second, the fact that you can write `for line in in_file:` means that an `in_file` is some kind of sequence of lines. So, if all you want to do is convert it to a `list` of lines, you can do that in one step:

```
data = list(in_file)
```

But really, the only reason you want this list in the first place is so you can loop around it later, creating the output files, right? So why not just hold off, and loop over the lines in the file in the first place?

Whatever you do to generate the output stuff, do that first. Then loop over the file with the list of filenames and write stuff. Like this:

```
stuff = # whatever you were doing later, in the code you haven't shown

dir = os.path.dirname(names)
with open(names, 'r') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        temp = os.path.join(dir, '{}.xls'.format(line))
        with open(temp, 'w') as out_file:
            out_file.write(stuff)
```

That replaces all of the code in your sample (except for that function named `high_throughput` that imports some modules locally and then does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`openpyxl`](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/), especially if you need to create `.xlsx` files. Below example assumes the Excel workbooks are created as blank.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
names = ['Eleen','Josh','Robert','Nastaran','Miles']
for name in names:
    wb = Workbook()
    wb.save('{0}.xlsx'.format(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
in_file=open(names,'r')
dir,file=os.path.split(names)

for name in in_file:
    temp = os.path.join(dir, name + '.xls')
    with open(temp,'w') as out_file:
        # write data to out_file
```